# How to configure AutoMapper to flatten a 1:n relation?

Tags: list, mapping, viewmodel, automapper, relation

Consider two entity classes **CD** and **Track**:

```
public class CD
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public IList<Track> Tracks {get; set;}
}

public class Track
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public CD CD {get; set;}
}
```

And consider the **CDTrackModel**:

```
public class CDTrackModel
{
    public long CdId {get; set;}
    public string CdName {get; set;}
    public long TrackId {get; set;}
    public string TrackName {get; set;}
}
```

And the GUI should be like the red table:
[image: CDTRACKMODEL]

Automapper mappings:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CD, CDTrackModel>()
.ForMember(vm => vm.CDId, o => o.MapFrom(m => m.Id)
.ForMember(vm => vm.CDName, o => o.MapFrom(m => m.Name)
// How to map the Tracks ???
;
```

Is it possible to create the required mapping using AutoMapper ?

Comment: How would you write this code without AutoMapper? That gives me the best direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion from Jimmy points me in the right direction...

Why not just map the **Track** Entity to the **CDTrackModel** instead of mapping the **CD** entity to the **CDTrackModel**?

The code would be:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Track, CDTrackModel>()
.ForMember(vm => vm.TrackId, o => o.MapFrom(m => m.Id)
.ForMember(vm => vm.TrackName, o => o.MapFrom(m => m.Name)
.ForMember(vm => vm.CDId, o => o.MapFrom(m => m.CD.Id)
.ForMember(vm => vm.CDName, o => o.MapFrom(m => m.CD.Name)
;
```